# Null Check before Assignment

Tags: c#, null, operators, extension-methods, static-methods

Is there a way to check for `null` before the ***assignment*** operation without using the `if` statement?
Is there a way to provide the following functionality in a single line similar to the null coalescing operator(`??`) or extension method:

```
if(myVar != null){ obj = myVar;}
```

I tried to use an extension method but extension methods don't allow the use of the `ref` or `out` keywords as the first parameter. I can't seem to find any built in operator that does this.

The point is to avoid the assignment because the `obj`'s propertyset property is set to true no matter what it is being set to `null` or otherwise.

meaning `obj = myVar ?? null;` will not work, nor will `obj = myVar != null ? myVar : null;`

I could possible use a static method but where should the method live? Utility class? A static method in an object extension class?

Are these the only options single line ifs or static methods?

**EDIT:**
I don't have access to the `obj` it is one of many third party objects provided to me as is.

**EDIT 2:**
I have a large amount of code that looks similar to the following:

```
this.Header.InvoiceHeader.InvoiceTypeCode = row.Field<string>("InvoiceTypeCode");
this.Header.InvoiceHeader.PurchaseOrderDate = row.Field<DateTime?>( "PODate" ) ?? DateTime.Now;
this.Header.InvoiceHeader.PurchaseOrderNumber = row.Field<string>( "PONumber" );
this.Header.InvoiceHeader.SellersCurrency = row.Field<string>( "Currency" ) ?? "USD";
this.Header.InvoiceHeader.BuyersCurrency = row.Field<string>( "Currency" ) ?? "USD";
this.Header.InvoiceHeader.TradingPartnerId = this.EDITradingPartner.TradingPartnerID;
this.Header.InvoiceHeader.CustomerAccountNumber = row.Field<string>("CustomerAccountNumber");
this.Header.InvoiceHeader.CustomerOrderNumber = row.Field<string>("CustomerOrderNumber");
this.Header.InvoiceHeader.PromotionDealNumber = row.Field<string>("PromotionDealNumber");
```

This is mapping my db to a third party xml object that has too many nodes to write a wrapper for each node. The xml object outputs an empty tag if the value of the property is **set** to `null`. in other words if I don't want the tag to exist then don't set it.

Comment: Why are you trying to make your code unreadable?

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to do? Could you post a full code example? because this isn't making much sense.

Comment: @Dennis I'm trying to do just the opposite I want to make it more clear(by use of extension method with descriptive name)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I have edited the question with a small snippet of the code i'm working with.

Comment: Extension methods certainly do allow `ref` or `out`, just not for the first parameter (i.e. the `this` parameter). But it doesn't matter anyway, because the issue you are trying to address exists only when dealing with properties, and you can't pass a property by-reference.

Comment: Ok well the first parameter would be what I want it to be and ment. I will edit to be more precise, and to eliminate future confusion.

Comment: The edit more correctly expresses your intent, but it still misleads, since the only way by-reference passing would be relevant is when not passing property values, but of course you are only dealing with properties here. I.e. even bringing up by-reference makes it sound like some variation on that would work, but it wouldn't in any case. Since you're dealing with properties, I'd recommend you just don't even mention by-reference passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use some method. If you will use this logic in different classes util class is what you need, otherwise use private method, or inherit from base class with protected implementation.

```
private void SetValue(ref object property, object value)
{
   if (property != null) {
      property = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: I will be using a static method in a utility class to complete the task at hand.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a smart setter, that actually knows when it's value *changed* instead of just checking whether it was *called*, you could do this:

```
obj = myVar ?? obj;
```

If you don't have a smart setter, there is no way around an `if`. Where you want to place that is completely up to your and your coding preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm assuming that `obj` is a variable and not a property, this is the equivalent, but personally I find the `if` much easier to read:

```
obj = myVar ?? obj;
```

Note that if `obj` is just a variable then there are no side-effects when setting it to itself, however if you try this with a *property*:

```
obj.MyProperty = myVar ?? obj.MyProperty;
```

Then you are invoking a getter and setter if `myVar` is null; either of which may have side effects that would not occur with the original `if` statement.

Comment: does this avoid the assignment altogether? or does it just assign it to its self?

Comment: It just sets it to itself.